# How I can enable force touch on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I want to use Apple Magic Trackpad 2 on ubuntu.
This trackpad supporting force touch.

How I can enable force touch on ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Did you try the `https://github.com/5argon/MacbookUbuntuTrackpad` solution?